# Is it posible to execute a Push Notification from Socket.io?

Tags: laravel, websocket, push-notification, socket.io

I have an api for an IOS / android app.

For the push notifications I decided to go with davibennun/laravel-push-notification and the app also has a chat system based on Socket.Io

The push notifications work like a charm but I have a question.

How can I make it possible to call upon a push from Socket.Io ?

A normal push is made like this

```
PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
            ->to($deviceToken)
            ->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to call a laravel static function from Socket.Io to ?
Or create a event listener that I can constantly listen in my backend so when it emits something to execute a push ?

Or any kind of ideas.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

```
                var pushUrl ='url to method;
                console.log('url:',pushUrl);
               https.get(pushUrl, (res) => {
                    console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
                console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    process.stdout.write(d);
            });

        }).on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
    });
```